# Date Format Conversion In Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a date item  `' Order_TCD'` in the form.

My requirement is when user enters Order_TCD it should be in the format:

```
DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIPM,
```

But the data in the report should appear in the format `DD-MON-YY.`

Comment: Be more specific about "the form". Is the item concerned an actual page item or is it in a tabular form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIPM

If `Order_TCD` is DATE data type, then while inserting the row you need to use **TO_DATE** and required **format mask**. You must specify the user to enter the date in the format `DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIPM`. And you need to handle it as:

```
TO_DATE('05-MAY-2015 11:05AM','DD-MON-YYYY HH:MIPM')
```

> But the data in the report should appear in the format DD-MON-YY.

To display the date in your desired format, you need to use **TO_CHAR**.

For example,

```
TO_CHAR(Order_TCD, 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the format mask on the (datepicker!) item, simply edit the item and go to the "Settings" section. You can enter the format mask there.

[image: Item format mask]

To display with another format mask in the report, you can set the format mask in the column attributes. Example here for an interactive report.
[image: Report column format mask]

You could also apply the mask on the column in the source SQL of course. Also note that you can set a global application date format mask in the globalization options of the application.

Comment: The date format model will override at individual SQL level over the tool NLS settings.

Comment: @LalitKumarB What do you mean? That using the format mask in the source sql will overrule the formatting set in the apex settings? If so, you are of course correct. But it would be a bad idea to combine both. Ideally, you steer behaviour via the globalization options, and only deviate when you have a requirement that specifies a certain format - such as a timepicker. That way your whole application will be quite uniform. Also, OP asked about user input. With the standard processes and items in place, the only place you need a mask is in the item itself. But the process is not specified anyway.

Comment: Hi @Tom, nothing fancy here. I just had a small point. And it was all about the order of precedence of the date format mask. Regarding taking input values via application, probably is out of scope of my comment. To make it easy, what I mean is [this](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/). Just look for the order of precedence in that link. That's all what I meant :-) By the way, thanks for your reply.